# How to insert random numbers into an array and sort them

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random

My code is supposed to take the random number generated in the random method and sort them but it's only giving me one number.

My program is a random number generator that is supposed to make 1000 numbers that I can sort but my code only inserts one number into the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write

    int max = 1000;
    int min=0;
    int range = max - min + 1;

    // generate random numbers within 1 to 10
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random () * range) + min;
        System.out.println ( rand );




        int array[] = {rand};
        int size = array.length;

        for ( i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            int min1 = i;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                if (array[j] < array[min1]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = array[min1];
            array[min1] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `int array[] = {rand};` does ?

Comment: What do you mean sort the number? And you're only getting 1 output because `array` only has one element.

Comment: My random number generator is only passing one number when it belongs to be passing 1000 numbers.

Comment: and for every iteration of your loop of one thousand you are doing `int array[] = {rand};`  - that is creating a new array with one element in it

Comment: How do I code it  so it takes 1000 elements?

Comment: Declare `array` outside the loop. Then set `array[i] = rand` inside the loop.

Comment: You also need to sort `array` *after* all the numbers have been inserted.

Comment: You can use 2 for-loops for this. One is to generate random number for each element in array. And the other one is to sort them. BTW, you should declare an array with fixed size first.

Comment: I had a lot of , mistakes thank you for the help. I will try everything now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break your program into separate steps:

1. Insert all the random numbers into the array
2. Sort the array
3. Print the contents of the array

Few problems I noticed:

1. Since you want to generate 1000 numbers from 1-10, `max` and `min` should have values of 10 and 1, respectively.
2. `array` should be declared *before* you start inserting values. It should also have a fixed size of 1000.
3. Your bubble sort algorithm also had some errors which led to incorrect output. If you wish to sort the array from greatest to least instead, simply change the `>` to `<` in the condition of the `if` statement.

I also decided to use `Arrays.toString()` to print the array instead of the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max = 10;
    int min = 1;
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int size = 1000;
    int[] array = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * range + min);
        array[i] = rand;
    }

    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < size - i; j++) {
            if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
                temp = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will result an ArrayIndexOutException. below is the code change from your code ,i dont change too much so you can compare them and  find your mistakes,wish good :D

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int max = 1000;
    int min=0;
    int range = max - min + 1;


    int[] array = new int[range];
    // generate random numbers within 1 to 10
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random () * range) + min;
        array[i] = rand;
    }

    int size = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int min1 = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[min1]) {
                min1 = j;//here min1
            }
        }
        int temp = array[min1];
        array[min1] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[k]);
    }
}
```

let me explain it more clearly,in the OP's code there has some questions,two majors:
one:

```
for ( i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        int min1 = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[min1]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        int temp = array[min1];
        array[min1] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
```

will never run,because the array size is 1 ,so the for loop phrase will be ignore without running(mean for(int i = 0; i < 0; i++){....}).

two:

```
for (int k = 0; k < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
    }
```

beacause the array size is 1,so when array[1] will throw index out exception.so the outermost loop will just run once then throw a exception.

:D

Comment: You might want to review your code. Your assumptions do not reflect OP's requirements as suggested by his code. For example, why is your array `range` elements? Why would OP be iterating 1000 times?